# positioning logo and navigation links not aligning

Tags: html, css, positioning

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: http://i36.tinypic.com/dfxdmd.jpg]

The yellow block is the logo and the blue box is the nav links (I have blanked them out). I would like to align the links at the bottom so they are stuck to the top of the body content (white box). How would I do this?
Here is the relevant CSS and HTML.

```
#header {
    height: 42px;
}
#logo {
    width: 253px;
    height: 42px;
    background-image:url(logo.png);
    float: left;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3edff2;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #3edff2;
    padding: 5px;
}

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><a href="/"></a></div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">*****</a></li>
                            [...]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Seems to work in Firefox/Mac

```
#header {
    height: 42px;
}
#logo {
    width: 253px;
    height: 42px;
    background: #00ffff;
    float: left;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3edff2;
    height: 42px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #3edff2;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That works on FF/XP. For IE  I had to add a margin-top: -20px attribute to the page element.

Comment: Although, if the user's fonts were slightly different (Linux?) wouldn't it be a bit misaligned?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom left? If so - start by setting `clear: both;` on your #nav block.

Other than that, I don't really understand your question - can you make a jpg of how you'd like it to look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning like this:

```
#header {
    position: relative;

    height: 42px;
}
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3edff2;
    height: 42px;
}
```

in this method, you make "nav" with absolute positioning related to "header" division.